# li Background Image Not Showing

Tags: html-lists, anchor, background-image

I have looked through a tonne of posts which have similar issues, but I just can't figure out my problem.   Please could someone help, it is driving me insane.

The below code is for my Site Navigation.  I would like the background to be an image rather than just a background colour.   I would also like the background image to change on hover.   As our Meerkat friends would say...Simples!....but not for me.

```
<div class="sub-menu" id="sub-menu">
<ul>
<li><a class="on" href="#" title=" You Are Here ">&raquo; Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="graduates-endorsements.html" title=" What Clients Say About The Programme ">Endorsements</a></li>
<li><a href="graduates-programme.html" title=" Programme Focus, Programme Leader and Venues ">The Detail</a></li>
<li><a href="graduates-funding.html" title=" Delegate Sponsored Places and Busaries ">Funding</a></li>
<li><a href="graduates-apply.html" title=" Online application Form ">Apply Online</a></li>
<li><a class="end" href="graduates-terms.html" title=" Terms &amp; Conditions ">Terms</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


div.sub-menu { position: relative; width: 920px; height: 40px; padding: 0; margin: 0;  border-top: solid 1px #FFFFFF; }
#sub-menu ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#sub-menu li { float: left; margin: 0; }
#sub-menu li a { padding: 0 30px; width: 93px; height: 40px; line-height: 36px; text-align: center; float: left; display: block; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; background-color: #555555; border-right: solid 1px #858585; }
#sub-menu li a:hover { color: #050505; background-color: #f3b607; }
#sub-menu li a.on { background-color: #555555; color: #FBAF5D; cursor: default; }
#sub-menu li a.end { width: 89px; }
#sub-menu li a.end-on { text-align: center; float: left; display: block; color: #FBAF5D; text-decoration: none; border-right: none; }


/* Hide from IE5-Mac \*/
#sub-menu li a{ float: none }
/* End hide */

#sub-menu { font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: verdana; }
```

Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your question subject, you said you wish to put background image to "li" tag, but as per the code you have shown, you have given background to "a" tag.

You can put background image and color both together to any of the tag "li" and "a"

Eg.
background: #00ff00 url('smiley.gif') no-repeat fixed center; 
For details refer:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

If you want to put hover effect as well, implement it on anchor "a" tag. Because old browsers like ie6 doesn't have inbuilt support for li hover effect.

Use following pattern.

```
a{
   background:   url('img1') no-repeat fixed center; 
}
a:hover{
   background:   url('img2') no-repeat fixed center; 
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I can't work out how to reply to you. I want to put the ammended code in but it wont let me. Unfortunately your suggestion did not work. If you have any other suggestions I would be extremely grateful. Thank you for all your help.